# Redirect all URLs containing querystrings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Using .htaccess how can I 301 redirect all URLs containing a querystring to the "canonical" version of the URL?

Example:

www.example.com/?bla_bla should redirect to www.example.com/

www.example.com/test/?bla_bla_evil_querystring should redirect to www.example.com/test/

www.example.com/test.html?bla_bla should redirect to www.example.com/test.html

I am looking for a site-wide solution to redirect any URL with querystrings to the same URL withouth querystrings.

Thank you!

Comment: What if there is any useful query string for your URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be with mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [R,QSD,L]
```

This rule matches if the query string is at least 1 character long. The `QSD` flag will discard the query string. The `R` flag will cause a redirect. After you've tested that this rule works as expected, replace the `R` flag with `R=301` to make the redirect permanent.

On versions where the `QSD` flag is not yet implemented, you can use the following code instead. Please note that this will leave a trailing `?` behind your url's, but there is nothing I can do about that. Consider upgrading your Apache to the latest version.

```
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R,L]
```

Comment: Using this, will the search engins see a 301 redirect? Forgot to say it: Thank you! :)

Comment: Actually, I forgot to add the redirect completely. I have edited my answer somewhat.

Comment: Thanks again! Will do some testing today and I will come back with an accepted answer.

Comment: Hello. Me again. It does not work, I just get an "Internal server error" after I add this to my .htaccess...

Comment: It appears that the QSD flag only works from Apache v2.4.0 and up. I have a lower version. Any alternatives to QSD ?

Comment: Use `RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R,L]` instead. This will replace the query string with an empty one. You get a trailing `?` behind your url's though, but there is nothing I can do about that. Consider upgrading your Apache version.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.